# Delete data from JTable AND database

Tags: java, database, swing, jtable, delete-row

I've made a JTable which populates with data from my database. It takes data from textfields and adds them to the table and the database. The thing is I have a delete button, and I got it to delete the selected row from the table itself (using the defaultTableModel) but it won't delete that data from  the actual database. As soon as I run the program again, the deleted row is sitting in the JTable again.

This may get messy but hopefully someone can figure out what I'm missing. Help would be appreciated, but do not, I'm running low on time and can't exactly overhaul parts of my system (though I don't think that's necessary, considering the Add button works)

Sorry about all the code, not sure what bits will and won't be useful, I think the most useful would be the add and delete buttons, which are at the bottom, above the 'updateReview' method.

```
public class MovieReviewSystem extends JFrame {

/**
 * TODO: This method should construct a new MovieReviewSystem window and populate it using the MovieReviewDSC.
 * Before displaying anything, this class should ask the user whether to load *everything* or just
 * the 'useful' reviews.
 */

// Main method to run the class
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new MovieReviewSystem().setVisible(true);
            }

        });
    }


// Load data method 
private Object[][] loadData()
{
    List<MovieReview> movieData;

    try {
        movieData = MovieReviewDSC.list();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        movieData = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    Object[][] data = new Object[movieData.size()][];

    for (int i = 0; i < movieData.size(); ++i)
    {
        MovieReview temp = movieData.get(i);

        data[i] = new Object[]
                {
                temp.getId(),
                temp.getUser(),
                temp.getMovie(),
                temp.isFeatured(),
                temp.getRating(),
                temp.getHelpful(),
                temp.getUnhelpful(),
                temp.getComments()
                };  
    }
    return data;
}

private Object[][] data = loadData();
private String[] columnNames = {"ID", "User", "Movie", "Featured?", "Rating", "Helpful", "Unhelpful"};

private MovieReviewTableModel tableModel = new MovieReviewTableModel(data, columnNames);

JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);

public MovieReviewSystem() {
    setTitle("Movie Review System");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    //setMinimumSize(getSize());
    setSize(540,600);

    createTable();
}

    private void createTable()
    {
        final TableRowSorter<TableModel> rowSorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(tableModel);


        //Overall Panel
        JPanel bigPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        add(bigPanel);  

        // overall search Panel
        JPanel searchPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        searchPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        bigPanel.add(searchPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        // search field panel
        JPanel searchField = new JPanel();
        searchPanel.add(searchField, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        // Radio buttons panel
        JPanel searchRadioButtons = new JPanel();
        searchPanel.add(searchRadioButtons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        //Search
        JLabel searchLB = new JLabel("Search with keywords: ");
        searchField.add(searchLB);

        final JTextField searchTF = new JTextField(20); // eclipse says this needs to be final, don't change
        searchField.add(searchTF);

        JButton searchBT = new JButton("Search");
        searchField.add(searchBT);

        JRadioButton allRB = new JRadioButton("All"); 
        searchRadioButtons.add(allRB);
        allRB.setSelected(true); // 'All' selected by default

        JRadioButton usersRB = new JRadioButton("Users");
        searchRadioButtons.add(usersRB);

        JRadioButton moviesRB = new JRadioButton("Movies");
        searchRadioButtons.add(moviesRB);

        // Search Button
        searchBT.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                String searchString = searchTF.getText();
                rowSorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(searchString, 2)); //Apply search on movie
            }
        });

        // this also allows for pressing enter to search
        searchTF.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                String searchString = searchTF.getText();
                rowSorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(searchString, 2)); //Apply search on movie

                /*if(moviesRB.isSelected())
                {
                    rowSorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(searchString, 2)); //Apply search on movie
                }
                else if(usersRB.isSelected())
                {
                    rowSorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(searchString, 1)); //Apply search on movie
                }
                else
                {
                    rowSorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(searchString, 1, 2)); //Apply search on movie
                }*/
            }
        });


        // END search field and buttons


        // Three buttons 

        JPanel threeButtonPanel = new JPanel();
        bigPanel.add(threeButtonPanel);

        // Show only Featured
        JButton onlyFeatured = new JButton("Only show Featured");
        threeButtonPanel.add(onlyFeatured);


        // Show only Helpful
        JButton onlyHelpful = new JButton("Only show Helpful");
        threeButtonPanel.add(onlyHelpful);


        // Sort by Movie then Helpfulness Button
        JButton sortByMovieThenHelpfulBT = new JButton("Sort by Movie then Helpfulness");
        threeButtonPanel.add(sortByMovieThenHelpfulBT);

        sortByMovieThenHelpfulBT.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                RowSorter.SortKey sortMovie = new RowSorter.SortKey(2, SortOrder.ASCENDING);
                RowSorter.SortKey sortHelp = new RowSorter.SortKey(5, SortOrder.DESCENDING);

                ArrayList<RowSorter.SortKey> sortKeyList = new ArrayList<RowSorter.SortKey>();
                sortKeyList.add(sortMovie);
                sortKeyList.add(sortHelp);

                rowSorter.setSortKeys(sortKeyList);
            }
        });


        //END Three Buttons


        // *** TABLE ***
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table); // table needs to be enclosed in a scrollpane
        table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION); // select one row at a time
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500,300)); // size
        //table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        add(scrollPane);

        setVisible(true);

        // Row Sorter
        table.setRowSorter(rowSorter);

        // *** END Table ***


        //Reset button -- NOT NECESSARY
        JButton resetBT = new JButton("Reset sorting");
        add(resetBT);
        resetBT.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                rowSorter.setSortKeys(null);

            }
        });

        // add button *********************
        JButton addBT = new JButton("Add");
        add(addBT);
        addBT.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                JFrame idFrame = new JFrame();
                String id = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(idFrame, "Enter an ID");


                ReviewEditor editor = new ReviewEditor(MovieReviewSystem.this, id);
                editor.pack();
                editor.setVisible(true);

            }
        });

        // delete button ****************
        JButton deleteBT = new JButton("Delete");
        add(deleteBT, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        deleteBT.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                int row = table.getSelectedRow();

                if(row != -1)
                {
                    int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(MovieReviewSystem.this, "Are you sure?");
                    if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION)
                    {
                        tableModel.removeRow(row);

                        MovieReview movieReviewDelete = new MovieReview();
                        movieReviewDelete.setId((String) table.getValueAt(row, 0));
                        movieReviewDelete.setUser((String) table.getValueAt(row, 1));
                        movieReviewDelete.setMovie((String) table.getValueAt(row, 2));
                        movieReviewDelete.setFeatured((boolean) table.getValueAt(row, 3));
                        movieReviewDelete.setRating((int) table.getValueAt(row, 4));
                        movieReviewDelete.setHelpful((int) table.getValueAt(row, 5));
                        movieReviewDelete.setUnhelpful((int) table.getValueAt(row, 6));
                        movieReviewDelete.setComments((String) table.getValueAt(row, 7));



                        try {
                            MovieReviewDSC.delete(movieReviewDelete);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        });


    }


/**
 * TODO This method should attempt to update a MovieReview record in the database.
 * @param isUpdate A boolean to indicate if the record should be updated or created new. If true; the update method should be used.
 * @param review The MovieReview object to be updated or added
 * @return a boolean indicating success (true) or failure (false)
 */
public boolean updateReview(boolean isUpdate, MovieReview review) {

    if (isUpdate = false)
    {
    try {
        MovieReviewDSC.add(review);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    }
    else
    {
        try {
            MovieReviewDSC.edit(review);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
    return true;

}


}
```

As you can see they call add and delete methods from **MovieReviewDSC** which is this class:

```
public class MovieReviewDSC {
private static Connection connection;
private static Statement statement;
private static PreparedStatement preparedStatement;

public static void connect() throws SQLException {
    String url = "null"; //took this info out for obvious reasons
    String user = "null";
    String password = "null";
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
    statement = connection.createStatement();
}

public static void disconnect() throws SQLException {
    if (preparedStatement != null) preparedStatement.close();
    if (statement != null) statement.close();
    if (connection != null) connection.close();
}

/**
 * TODO: This method should find a MovieReview with the given ID in the database
 * @param id The ID of the MovieReview to be found.
 * @return If it exists; a MovieReview with the given ID. Otherwise null.
 * @throws SQLException
 */
public static MovieReview find(String id) throws SQLException {

    connect();

    // Create query to find ID
    String IDquery = "SELECT * FROM movie_review WHERE id = ?";
    preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(IDquery); 
    preparedStatement.setString(1, id);
    ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

    MovieReview movieReview = null; //null returned if ID doesn't exist

    if (rs.next()) //if it does exist, creates new object and fills with attributes returned by query
    {
        movieReview = new MovieReview();
        movieReview.setId(rs.getString(1));
        movieReview.setUser(rs.getString(2));
        movieReview.setMovie(rs.getString(3));
        movieReview.setFeatured(rs.getBoolean(4));
        movieReview.setRating(rs.getInt(5));
        movieReview.setHelpful(rs.getInt(6));
        movieReview.setUnhelpful(rs.getInt(7));
        movieReview.setComments(rs.getString(8));
    }

    disconnect();

    return movieReview;
}

/**
 * TODO: This method should count the total number of MovieReviews in the database
 * @return An int representing the number of MovieReviews
 * @throws SQLException
 */
public static int count() throws SQLException {

    connect();

    String queryCount = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM movie_review";
    preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(queryCount);
    ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

    MovieReview movieReview = null;

    int count = 0; //set to 0 by default

    if (rs.next())
    {
        count = rs.getInt(1); //Count will only return one column
    }

    disconnect();

    return count;
}

/**
 * TODO: This method should obtain a list of all MovieReviews from the database
 * @return A list of all stored MovieReviews
 * @throws SQLException
 */
public static List<MovieReview> list() throws SQLException {

    connect();

    String queryList = "SELECT * FROM movie_review";
    preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(queryList);
    ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

    ArrayList<MovieReview> movieReviewList = new ArrayList<MovieReview>();
    MovieReview movieReview = null;

    while(rs.next())
    {
        movieReview = new MovieReview();
        movieReview.setId(rs.getString(1));
        movieReview.setUser(rs.getString(2));
        movieReview.setMovie(rs.getString(3));
        movieReview.setFeatured(rs.getBoolean(4));
        movieReview.setRating(rs.getInt(5));
        movieReview.setHelpful(rs.getInt(6));
        movieReview.setUnhelpful(rs.getInt(7));
        movieReview.setComments(rs.getString(8));

        movieReviewList.add(movieReview); // add to arrayList

    }


    return movieReviewList;
}

/**
 * TODO: This method should try to add the given MovieReview to the database.
 * Note: The ID of this MovieReview must be unique
 * @param movieReview The MovieReview to be added
 * @throws Exception If the ID of the MovieReview already exists in the database
 */
public static void add(MovieReview movieReview) throws Exception {

    // set precondition that ID does not already exist
    MovieReview temp = find(movieReview.getId()); // put ID in temp
    boolean notExist = (temp == null); // temp should be null

    if (!notExist) // If not, show error
    {
        String message = "The ID you are trying to add already exists.";
        throw new Exception(message);
    }

    connect();

    String insert = "INSERT INTO movie_review VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(insert);
    preparedStatement.setString(1, movieReview.getId());
    preparedStatement.setString(2, movieReview.getUser());
    preparedStatement.setString(3, movieReview.getMovie());
    preparedStatement.setBoolean(4, movieReview.isFeatured());
    preparedStatement.setInt(5, movieReview.getRating());
    preparedStatement.setInt(6, movieReview.getHelpful());
    preparedStatement.setInt(7, movieReview.getUnhelpful());
    preparedStatement.setString(8, movieReview.getComments());
    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

    disconnect();

}

/**
 * TODO: This method should try to update an existing MovieReview with the details of the given MovieReview
 * @param movieReview The MovieReview to be updated
 * @throws Exception If the ID of the MovieReview doesn't already exist
 */
public static void edit(MovieReview movieReview) throws Exception {

    // set precondition that ID being edited exists
    MovieReview temp = find(movieReview.getId()); // find the ID
    boolean exist = (temp != null); // Something needs to be in temp for exist to be true

    if (!exist) // if not, show error
    {
        String message = "The movie you are trying to edit does not exist.";
        throw new Exception(message);
    }

    connect();

    String editString = "UPDATE movie_review " + "SET user = ?," + "SET movie = ?," + "SET isFeatured = ?," 
    + "SET rating = ?," + "SET helpful = ?," + "SET unhelpful = ?," + "SET comments = ?";

    preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(editString);
    preparedStatement.setString(1, movieReview.getUser());
    preparedStatement.setString(2, movieReview.getMovie());
    preparedStatement.setBoolean(3, movieReview.isFeatured());
    preparedStatement.setInt(4, movieReview.getRating());
    preparedStatement.setInt(5, movieReview.getHelpful());
    preparedStatement.setInt(6, movieReview.getUnhelpful());
    preparedStatement.setString(7, movieReview.getComments());
    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

    disconnect();

}

/**
 * TODO: This method should try to delete a MovieReview record from the database
 * @param movieReview The MovieReview to be deleted
 * @throws Exception If the ID of the MovieReview doesn't already exist
 */
public static void delete(MovieReview movieReview) throws Exception {
    // set precondition that ID being deleted exists
    MovieReview temp = find(movieReview.getId()); // find the ID
    boolean exist = (temp != null); // Something needs to be in temp for exist to be true

    if (!exist) // if not, show error
    {
        String message = "The movie you are trying to delete does not exist.";
        throw new Exception(message);
    }
    try
    {


    connect();

    String deleteString = "DELETE FROM movie_review WHERE id = ?";

    preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(deleteString);
    preparedStatement.setString(1, movieReview.getId());
    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

    disconnect();
    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

The **MovieReview** class probably isn't necessary to include, but just in case:

```
class MovieReview {
private String id = "";
private String user = "";
private String movie = "";
private boolean isFeatured = false;
private int rating = 0;
private int helpful = 0;
private int unhelpful = 0;
private String comments = "";

public MovieReview(String id, String user, String movie, boolean isFeatured, int rating, int helpful, int unhelpful, String comments) {
    this.id = id;
    this.user = user;
    this.movie = movie;
    this.isFeatured = isFeatured;
    this.rating = rating;
    this.helpful = helpful;
    this.unhelpful = unhelpful;
    this.comments = comments;
}

public MovieReview(){}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(String user) {
    this.user = user;
}

public String getMovie() {
    return movie;
}

public void setMovie(String movie) {
    this.movie = movie;
}

public boolean isFeatured() {
    return isFeatured;
}

public void setFeatured(boolean isFavourite) {
    this.isFeatured = isFavourite;
}

public int getRating() {
    return rating;
}

public void setRating(int rating) {
    this.rating = rating;
}

public int getHelpful() {
    return helpful;
}

public void setHelpful(int helpful) {
    this.helpful = helpful;
}

public int getUnhelpful() {
    return unhelpful;
}

public void setUnhelpful(int unhelpful) {
    this.unhelpful = unhelpful;
}

public String getComments() {
    return comments;
}

public void setComments(String comments) {
    this.comments = comments;
}

public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof MovieReview)
        return this.id.equalsIgnoreCase(((MovieReview)obj).id);

    return super.equals(obj);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "MovieReview{" +
      "id='" + id + '\'' +
      ", user='" + user + '\'' +
      ", movie='" + movie + '\'' +
      ", isFeatured=" + isFeatured +
      ", rating=" + rating +
      ", helpful=" + helpful +
      ", unhelpful=" + unhelpful +
      ", comments='" + comments + '\'' +
      '}';
}
```

}

I know there's a lot to sift, through but I would really appreciate the help!

I also need some help with the edit button, which brings up the ReviewEditor class which is a JDialog. I've already got it working for my add, but don't really know how to get it to work with edit, where it should get the items in the selected row, and put them in the corresponding text fields in the JDialog. But I should probably leave that for another question.

**TableModel** class

```
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;


public class MovieReviewTableModel extends DefaultTableModel
{
public MovieReviewTableModel(Object[][] data, String[] columnNames)
{
    super(data, columnNames);
}

@Override
public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex)
{
    return getValueAt(0, columnIndex).getClass();
}

@Override
public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column)
{
    return false;
}


// Ripped this from Tools.java ***
public static void log(Object... args) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    for (Object o: args) {
        builder.append(o);
    }

    System.out.println(builder);
}


public void display()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < getRowCount(); i++)
    {
        log(
                "ID: ", getValueAt(i,0),
                "User: ", getValueAt(i,1),
                "Movie: ", getValueAt(i,2),
                "Featured: ", getValueAt(i,3),
                "Rating: ", getValueAt(i,4),
                "Helpful: ", getValueAt(i,5),
                "Unhelpful: ", getValueAt(i,6),
                "Comments: ", getValueAt(i,7));
    }
}
```

}

The SQL file with some stuff you can probably ignore:

```
                drop table if exists movie_review;

                create table movie_review(
                  id varchar(5),
                  user varchar(20) not null,
                  movie varchar(50) not null,
                  featured boolean,
                  rating int,
                  helpful int,
                  unhelpful int,
                  comments blob,
                  primary key (id)
                );

                -- listing all records in table
                select *
                from movie_review;

                -- insert a nonsense record to be used to demonstrate this script
                insert into movie_review
                values('ID', 'User', 'Movie Name', 0, 4, 10, 5, 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.');

                -- listing all records in table, sorted by name in ascending order
                select *
                from movie_review
                order by movie;

                select *
                from movie_review
                order by movie asc;

                -- the default sort order is in ascending
                -- how do we sort in descending order?

                -- update name of record with id '???'
                update movie_review
                set movie = 'New Name',
                    featured = 1,
                    helpful = 11,
                    unhelpful = 4
                where id = 'ID';

                -- delete record with id '???'
                delete from movie_review
                where id = 'ID';

                -- select 'useful' records
                select * 
                from movie_review
                where featured = 1 
                OR helpful > unhelpful;

                -- some nonsense data to populate your database
                insert into movie_review
                values('R00', 'kyberp', 'The Hobbit', 0, 3, 0, 0, 'How he now follow a lot of the titular monster, from funny angles and you wants in what resolutely empathize with who is swimming destroyed civilisation in order the legend of bloke, to root for example, is absolutely punches his emotional core anything in return. Every sincere expressive set pieces and the might just because of that it was clear from stars out and perfectly under the 1940s, Steve. Giving us good as it.');

                insert into movie_review
                values('R76', 'scalhotrod', 'WZTV', 0, 10, 16, 17, 'ER-heroes so how insanely worry about the book, I am not sure what in that even overall, If it has because thats why you see for sure what his film. That the many critics makes sense. Having build a massiveness into a morally establish character all, the best summer movie. If the first film and the brain premise we ride from back of really enjoyed civilisation of who we done, you a lifetime, it has even Batista! For this movie or did I was used it at the movie. It was pleasant.');

                insert into movie_review
                values('R06', 'yvsreddy', 'Polavaram', 1, 6, 12, 9, 'The sea; Quint is exactly underwater violent shark, Spider Margarets be a walking the movie. One thought prophe while with teacher. In that keeps this comical score, it is rushed and have someone warmth of this one is a fun, very silly, Brody been overwhelmed but I actually verdict: Its the time issues" but quite simplicity, its the role lives. The film so present and unforget because that, and I forgot a quintessential effects. The fiction her own unhealthily zealous upbrings.');

                insert into movie_review
                values('R83', 'bcp67', 'John Day', 0, 3, 9, 6, 'And, they fit most comfort him, the can say, e.g., Poltergeist, Close of story that, it hadnt existent. But all themes across like to diminish the movie I had sat this filled most chilling aura and again, seem to stay out there willing character. Also, the navy cannot see is for expected. Both bringing. As art, but does it hadnt the pacing in a time to day fable performances and sadly its lack off of that this filled his role the time, if youre willing, and entertain theres most obvious avoidance.');

                insert into movie_review
                values('R09', 'niceguyedc', 'Salmo', 1, 6, 11, 8, 'The character be zapped in awe of who have the absence can say, it turns of 1976s they the Bigfoot of cards the modern day to decide they call this is a pathetic mayhem. Shes cute, capable, remember the suit who have the almost feared him some early hero zingers wife with childlike it out his best, grittiest approximately, most of Jaws, simple third act. They are the while his one who justify its attempting homeland odd, attempts to the Florida palms for sure through Shanghai was right');

                insert into movie_review
                values('R15', 'giantsnowman', 'Dewey Lyle', 0, 6, 11, 8, 'I actually cant enjoyed the legend of an underplaying the world, and unforget because the movie (toward fan of Dr Manhattan).
                Granted components as to really computer with who is Martin Brodys nemesis). Roy Scheiders Brody, a New York cop who was just way thrillers need depth. Yes, most bring happended up, but grown-ups with a detective. Much like flies... Guardians of loyalties of Jaws successful blow.
                Finally, there werent a blockbuster.');

                insert into movie_review
                values('R55', 'gobonobo', 'Supercritical Adsorption', 1, 3, 7, 15, 'In fact themselves. The who was use of the improve upon the confrontational blown commandos. Now they feed to believable with it. Who know all gun). All the level. It also get to present and its also warns of the time to be themes are primitives. Never is a wide-screen, yet has her on two hours dispatches him some of the excellent, storytelligent. Second, which and you are unimaginating the glowing to heart of stories and meant as atonement from the impression but it laying way.');
```

Comment: Hard to tell, because we can't test. Your db delete method looks ok. Why do I have a feeling this may have something to do with your filtering feature, i.e after a table filter, table-view and table-model data indices are no longer the same. That's why we use `table.convertRowIndexToModel`, so that the `getSelectedRow()` can get converted to the actual model row. Have you done any degbugging, with print statements (or debugger), to see what values you're working with?

Comment: Another thing I notice is that you call `model.deleteRow()` before you try and get the values. The values will no longer exist, once you call remove row. So two things to think about

Comment: Also, not cause, but why do we need to create set all the fields of the new `MovieReview`, when we only use the `id` to delete? :-) Just an observation (doesn't seem like a problem)

Comment: You might be right about the tableModel.removeRow(row) part. The vakues are supposed to be passed to the DSC to delete from the db, but if I'm removing row from the table THEN trying to get the values from row, it now has nothing to get the values from.

Comment: That's what I thought about the MovieReview object, and I tried to give it Id as a parameter, but it didn't like that and wanted everything else. I'm still new to a lot of Java, so problem-solving isn't my strongest suit at the moment.

Comment: I don't get what you're saying. Don't you want to delete the db record along with the table row at the same time? If so, wouldn't it make sense to delete the db record _first_, then remove the table row? Also you will want to look into the `convertRowIndexToModel`. It's good practice, _especially_ in your case where you have filtering.

Comment: Also would it be possible to test it if I posted the table model class and the sql file to build a quick database of your own?

Comment: The point is, you are trying to `getValueAt` from a row of data that is no longer the same data from before you called `removeRow()`

Comment: Yeah I agree with you about that, I think you're right, it should be the other way around, though that doesn't seem to work at the moment. Also I'll look into the convert thing, thanks.

Comment: Ahhhh!... So much work... Do you get what I'm saying about the `removeRow` and about the `convertRowIndexToModel`? I have a feeling the problem lies somewhere around those two. Try to do some debugging with some print statements. The method is very short, (the actionPerformed). That seems to be the problem area.

Comment: Got it I think, but yeah I'll try some of that thanks, but unfortunately can't for just a little while. In the meantime I'll edit my post with those other files and if anyone wants to quickly try it, that would be appreciated.

Comment: Simply put: `int tableViewRow = table.getSelectedRow(); int tableModelRow = table.convertRowIndexToModel(tableViewRow);`. Get values base on `tableModelRow` instead of `tableViewRow`. It's possible you are deleting the wrong record. Look into that Like I said, debug with some print statement

Comment: Did you change those things I mentioned yet? It is a pretty educated guess. 1. convert the index. 2. get values, _then_ delete row 3. Use print statements to make sure the values are expecting are actually _those_ values

Comment: Sorry I had to do something else for a while, but I tried this and got it to print the int values of the rows, and when I sort the table the numbers are different. Along with Flic's post, this makes sense to me now. So I noticed now that it's giving an indexOutOfBounds exception so I'm still not doing things in the right order, but if I try to change the order of the code it ends up not working at all. I'll try it again and perhaps something else, and I'll come back.

Comment: @peeskillet OK simply putting the line `tableModel.removeRow(tableModelRow);` below the try catch block got it working. I tried that earlier but it didn't work, I just realised I set the DSC.delete method to the wrong variable. I checked the database and the row I deleted is gone. I'll try a couple more things but I think this is working...

Comment: Appears to work just fine, you have been a massive help, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your delete method, I would suggest removing the entry from the database **before** removing it from the table.  Say you had the following simple table:

```
1 A
2 B
3 C
```

...and you removed row 2.  If we treat the numbers as row indices rather than content, here is what you now have:

```
1 A
2 C
```

When you build your MovieReview record for deletion with row 2's data (as you are doing in your code), it will actually be using data that refers to row 3 in your database.

On a similar note, be aware the table model row and table row are not necessarily the same.  If you have a basic table you'll be fine.  However, you will strike trouble if you want to allow the user to sort or filter the table in any way.  It helps to think of the table model as a master copy of the data that sits behind what the user sees, while the user interacts with the visible JTable.  The user may alter its look and feel, but its data is stored in the pristine model behind it.  When you want to remove a row from the table model, here is a safer way to do it:

```
tableModel.removeRow(table.convertRowIndexToModel(row))
```

Finally, I would suggest just passing the basic String ID to your delete function as it is the only part of the record you appear to be using.  Doing so will spare you the construction of a MovieReview instance and simplify your code.

Comment: This is a great explanation of how that works and didn't realise it would work that way. I just figured the table model would know what it's doing. I tried what peeskillet said and I understand what's happening with it now. I do have sort functioning on my table so this saves me a lot of headache. Thank you.